# I need some help Write random test data to csv file using faker

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, faker

I am new to Python 2.7
I am trying to write some random test data to a csv file using the Python faker package.
I have stored a random first name value into a List variable called 'firstNameList' 
I then write the value to the csv using write_to_csv.writerow(firstNameList)

The value that is written out in the csv file is 
|('first_name', u'Monica')|

I just want the first name value in the csv e.g. Monica
I do not want the whole string |('first_name', u'Monica')| in the csv.

I have noticed my other first name variable firstName1 has the value Loraine 
This one would be great to use.  But when i try to write firstName1 to the csv the output is 
f i r s t _ n a m e

My code is below.
I am storing the value in a List variable because i want to populate a few rows in the csv.  Say 100 rows of random data.
If i store 100 first names into the names list variable I can then use a for loop to loop through the List and output the values to the csv file.
I will then do the same for address, email, phone etc.

```
from faker.factory import Factory
import csv

def writeTo_csv(fake):
    with open('test.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    write_to_csv = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|',     quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    write_to_csv.writerow(['id,', 'TITLE,', 'FNAME,', 'SNAME,', 'GENDER,',     'ADD1,', 'ADD2,', 'ADD3,', 'ADD4,', 'PCODE,', 'PHONE,', 'MOBILE,', 'DOB'])
    firstName1 = "first_name"
    firstNameList = [(firstName1, getattr(fake, firstName1)())]
    print "%s = %s" % (firstName1, getattr(fake, firstName1)())
    print firstNameList
    write_to_csv.writerow(firstName1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
fake = Factory.create('en_GB')
writeTo_csv(fake)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tuple inside a list, in the `firstNameList` variable. You have to extract the random name like:

```
firstNameList[0][1]
```

When printing, `writerow()` accepts an iterable data structure and separates each element with the delimiter specified in the constructor, so if you pass a string it assumes each letter as a field, you must create a list or a tuple with all your names to separate them right. In following example I used a tuple, like:

```
write_to_csv.writerow((firstNameList[0][1],))
```

So the script gets like:

```
from faker.factory import Factory
import csv 

def writeTo_csv(fake):
    with open('test.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        write_to_csv = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|',     quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        write_to_csv.writerow(['id,', 'TITLE,', 'FNAME,', 'SNAME,', 'GENDER,',     'ADD1,', 'ADD2,', 'ADD3,', 'ADD4,', 'PCODE,', 'PHONE,', 'MOBILE,', 'DOB'])
        firstName1 = "first_name"
        firstNameList = [(firstName1, getattr(fake, firstName1)())]
        print "%s = %s" % (firstName1, getattr(fake, firstName1)())
        print firstNameList
        write_to_csv.writerow((firstNameList[0][1],))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fake = Factory.create('en_GB')
    writeTo_csv(fake)
```

That yields a `test.csv` file like:

```
id, TITLE, FNAME, SNAME, GENDER, ADD1, ADD2, ADD3, ADD4, PCODE, PHONE, MOBILE, DOB
Dana
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. I can use the same pattern then for the address, phone, dob fields.  Cool!